# Crystal operators

Tags: combinatorics, representation-theory, algebraic-combinatorics

Define the operator $s_i$ on tableaux:

Consider letters $i$ and $i + 1$ in row reading word of the tableau.

Successively “bracket” pairs of the form (i + 1, I ).

Left with word of the form $i^r (i + 1)^s$.
Then

$$s_i(i^r(i+1)^s)=i^s(i+1)^r$$

Show that:

(a) $s_i^2(b)=b$,

(b) $s_is_j(b)=s_js_i(b)$ if $|i-j|>1$

(c) $s_is_{i+1}s_i(b)=s_{i+1}s_is_{i+1}(b)$

Part (a) is clear. Beacuse after two operations, powers remain unchanged. Part (b) is also clear because $s_i$ and $s_j$ do not interfere with each other as long as $|i-j|>1$.

Part(c) is known as braid property. It seems to be a little messy to show this property.

Comment: What does the second line mean? I am confused by "...in row reading word of the tableau."

Comment: Starting from the lowest row of tableau, write the numbers inserted in the boxes of the tableau from left to write. Then go to the upper row and so on so forth.

Comment: I find it a bit difficult to understand the presentation here, but this question feels familiar. Have you tried searching for earlier questions about braids?

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by "bracketing"? Do you mean that if you have some subword of the form $(i,i,i+1,i,i+1)$, then $s_i$ acts according to the rule $(i+1,i+1,i+1,i,i)$? (so you don't change the $(i+1,i)$ entry?)

Comment: If we have $(i+1,i+1,i,i)$, first we bracket $(i+1,i)$ then remove it from our sequence. Then $(i+1,i)$ remains. Again we bracket $(i+1,i)$ and remove it from the sequence.

Comment: But, you are operating on a tableau, so the end result is a tableau. You have not explained how to reconstruct the tableau $s_i(b)$. For example, if $\lambda=(4,3,2)$ and the reading word of a tableau $b$ is $(2,3,1,2,3,1,1,2,3)$, then is the reading word of $s_i(b)$ $(2,3,1,2,3,1,2,1,3)$?

Comment: No. Suppose that $i=1$ First we should remove all (2,1) from the list. If we do so only (1,2) remains. Since $r=s=1$ (using above notation), then (1,2) will be unchanged. So the $S_1(b)=b$.

Comment: If in the remaining list we have $1,1,1,2,2$, after the operation we would have $1,1,2,2,2$.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2969452/ . I regret to say I have not found the time to write up my proof yet :/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proof that the Lascoux-Schützenberger involutions satisfies the braid-relations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2969452/proof-that-the-lascoux-sch%c3%bctzenberger-involutions-satisfies-the-braid-relations)

Comment: @darijgrinberg:  The proposed duplicate asks for references, which you supplied, but here the request is for a proof.  I think it best to leave it open, hoping someone may be able to find the time to write it up.